# Error returned when running Bokeh template script

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh, seaborn

As per http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.0/docs/user_guide/charts.html#bar-charts I run the example in Jupyter, and replacing `output_file("bar.html")` with `output_notebook()`. However I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'references'
```

Does anyone have any idea why and how to fix it? I tried it with my own data and same error is returned.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 0.11 is not the latest. I also experiment some parameter changes between versions.
Did you tried with the latest version (0.12.13) ?

Comment: Whenever I try any of the example in any versions I get the same error from show(p). Tried this too: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#userguide-categorical

Comment: Hmm I did update to 0.12.13 and it took care of the issue. Leaves me wondering why, but I guess I can close

Comment: Bokeh is still a relatively young project and under active development. For instance the link in the original post, is to a `bokeh.charts` example. The `bokeh.charts` API was experimental, and was ultimately deprecated and removed entirely. For up to date information about categorical data and bar charts, etc. see https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html